# Cryptic error Closing Toplevel window Python 3 Canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, timer

No idea what the comments are on this.  But, never mind, I fixed it myself.

Took a while to figure out that Python is really sloppy and leaves timers running when you destroy the process completely.  Then a while later, you get a blow up when it comes out of the timer and has nowhere to go.  That's a very basic thing.  You clean up after yourself in a destroy operation.  Python does not.

I am able to open and close my toplevel window while keeping the main window going but I get a large, cryptic error message when I close the child window.  This happens both when I close it via the X or the defined button in the child window.  If I comment out the timer event (self.ater), the error messages do not come up.  But I have to have that to update the form.

The error message is coming up on the next timer pop.  It is not destroyed and pops but there is nowhere to go any longer.

I can't make the error message show up exactly right.  Did the best I could.

Here is the error message block, then the code to create and close the child window.

Exception in Tkinter callback

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1536, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/**init**.py", line 585, in callit
    func(*args)

File "/home/pi/IltiShares/@Mikes Files/@Python3 Source/GPS Data Show 11-02-2016.py", line 630, in UpdateSky
t_canvas.itemconfig(zz, text=str(self.counter))

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/**init**.py", line 2419, in itemconfigure
    return self._configure(('itemconfigure', tagOrId), cnf, kw)

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1313, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".1959370864.1959118928.1959118192.1959118800"

```
def ShowSky(self):

  global t_canvas
  global zz
  fontsize   = 8
  labelwidth = 15
  textwidth  = 17

  self.counter += 1
  t = Toplevel(self) 
  t.wm_title("Sky Map or SV's") 

  frame2 = Frame(t)
  frame2.config(height = 400, width = 400) # These are pixels
  frame2.config(relief = RIDGE)
  frame2.pack(side = LEFT, anchor= 'ne')

  t_canvas = Canvas(frame2, height = 300, width = 300, borderwidth = 2,
                     bg= '#b3ffff', relief = GROOVE)
  t_canvas.pack()

  self.waiting = StringVar()
  self.waiting.set('.')
  zz = t_canvas.create_text(50, 50, text = '01')
  Button(frame2, text='Close', width = 10, bg = '#FFc0c0',  command=t.destroy).pack()
  self.after(1000, self.UpdateSky)
pass

def UpdateSky(self):
  global t_canvas
  global zz
  self.counter += 1
  # Test movement and text change.
  t_canvas.itemconfig(zz, text=str(self.counter))
  t_canvas.coords(zz,self.counter,60)

  self.after(8000, self.UpdateSky)
pass
```

Comment: Are these methods part of a class? They have a parameter named `self`, but they use global variables and there's no `class` statement.

Comment: When you destroy the window, you need to cancel any pending `after` commands that might run after the window has been destroyed.